# DataGrid row to move the top

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

[image]

I need to move the checked rows from the suitability to under the prize us, or from the prize us to under the exact.

Comment: You need to provided us more information... Is this WPF ? Forms ? What is the type of your collection ? How do you order your items? The more info you give, the quicker the answer.

Comment: It looks like Winforms. But still your question is vague. What is your code? What have you tried. What is input? What is output?